# Regex remove everything else except one number

Tags: regex

I have a string consists of multiple lines (output from powershell) like

```
....
junk line
junk line
MyVaraible=xxxx
junk line
junk line
....
```

I need to use one regex to get rid of all the junk lines and extract the variable value.

It is super easy if I can loop thru all the lines where I can just do 
`"MyVaraible=(\d+)"` replace with `"$1"`

But I'm being super restricted by this ancient system where one regex replacement is all I am allow to do.

Comment: @anubhava no luck. says its not a match

Comment: Check this: https://regex101.com/r/7JHueE/1

Comment: @anubhava actually. the match worked but the replace still writes out the junk lines

Comment: ok check this: https://regex101.com/r/7JHueE/2

Comment: @anubhava beautiful! Type out the answer and I will accept it !

Comment: would the downvoter explain why this is a bad question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex based replacement.

Search using this regex:

```
/^\w+=(.*)$|.*(\n|\z)/
```

Replace using back-reference:

```
$1
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7JHueE/2)

RegEx `^\w+=(.*)$|.*(\n|\z)` matches a name-value pair separated by `=` or it matches a full line followed by line-break or end of string.